# On linearity of the Expected value

Tags: probability, statistics

Based on the definition of the expected value for a discrete random variable one has
$$E(X) = \sum_{all~x}^{}  P(X=x) \; x$$
But, when it comes to the proof of linearity of $E$, people usually write
$$E(X+Y) = \sum_{all~x,y}^{}  P(X=x, Y=y) \; (x+y)$$
Which does not align with the original definition which is
$$E(X+Y) = \sum_{all \; z}^{}  P(X+Y=z) \; z$$
My question is how the two latter definitions coincide while the probability distribution of $X +Y$ is not clear.

A similar question can be proposed for definition $E(f(X))$.

Comment: You can think $X + Y$ is a new random variable called $Z$, so if $X=x$ and $Y=y$ then $Z = X + Y = x + y = z$. Can you prove $P(X=x, Y = X) = P(Z = z)$ ?.

Comment: See [Law of the Unconscious Statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I'm assuming discrete variables, because you have a sum and not an integral.

For a fixed $z$, the event $(X+Y=z)$ can be partitioned into the events $\{(X=x,Y=z-x):x\in \mathcal{X}\}$, where $\mathcal{X}$ is the (countable) set of values $X$ can take. So $\mathbb{P}(X+Y=z)=\sum_x \mathbb{P}(X=x,Y=z-x)$. So $$\mathbb{E}(X+Y)=\sum_z \mathbb{P}(X+Y=z)z=\sum_z\sum_x\mathbb{P}(X=x,Y=z-x)z.$$ Letting $y=z-x$ and changing variables turns this into $\sum_{x,y}\mathbb{P}(X=x,Y=y)(x+y)$.

The same idea works for computing $E[f(X)]$. For each potential value $y$ that $f(X)$ can take, we take the event of $\{f(X)=y\}$, and split it into all the possible values $x$ that $X$ can take for which $f(X)=y$.
$$
E[f(X)]=\sum_y P(f(X)=y)y=\sum_y \sum_{x\in f^{-1}(y)} P(X=x)f(x)=\sum_x P(X=x)f(x).
$$
To explain the last equality, note that the set of values that $X$ can take is partitioned into sets of the form $f^{-1}(y)$, as $y$ ranges over the set of values $f(X)$ can take. Therefore, summing over $y$, and then summing over each part, is the same as summing over all $x$.

Comment: To me, finding a reason for merging to sigma to get $\sum_{x,y}\mathbb{P}(X=x,Y=y)(x+y)$ is same as the finding answer for the original question!

Answer (score 1):

Let $R_X := \{x \in \mathbb{R} \colon P(X = x) > 0\}$. Then $P(X \in R_X) = 1$. Similarily for $Y$ and $X+Y$. Note that $R_{X+X} \subset R_X + R_Y$. Then $1 = P(X+Y \in R_{X+Y}) \leq P(X+Y \in R_X + R_Y) = 1$  Assuming that all expectations exist, we get

$$\sum_{x,y \in R_X \times R_Y} P(X=x, Y=y)(x+y) =\\ \sum_{z \in R_{X+Y}} ~ \sum_{\{(x,y) \in R_X \times R_Y \colon x+y = z\}}P(X =x,Y = y)(x+y) =\\ \sum_{z \in R_{X+Y}} ~ \sum_{\{(x,y) \in R_X \times R_Y \colon x+y = z\}}P(X =x,Y = y)z = \sum_{z \in R_{X+Y}} P(X+Y = z)z = E(X+Y)$$
by the formula of total probability.